# SonataAdmin $formMapper->add('propertyA.propertyB');

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

how to do this:

```
$formMapper->add('propertyA.propertyB');
```

when

```
$this->propertyA->propertyB;

/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="propertyB")
*/
protected $propertyA;
```

$propertyA depend on entity A

$propertyB depend on entity B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do this

```
->add('name', 'text', array('property_path' => 'propertyA.propertyB', 'required' => false))
```